# Zfcuser route has a child route

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I'm working on a ZF2 project, and using ZfcUser to manage website users.
I just want to know is it possible to have a child route to the zfcuser route? 
Something like that, in the configuration of my module:

```
return [
        'router' =>
        [
            'routes' =>
            [
                'admin' =>
                [
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' =>
                    [
                        'route'    => '/admin',
                        'defaults' =>
                        [
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'admin',
                            'controller'    => 'admin.index',
                            'action'        => 'index',
                        ],
                    ],
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes'  =>
                    [
                        'zfcuser' =>
                        [
                            'type' => 'Literal',
                            'options' =>
                            [
                                'route' => '/account',
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                ],

            ],
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, point /admin/account to something that zfcuser provides?

Comment: I implemented Zfcuser in my project.
I now want to rewrite the routes of zfcuser, to properly integrate my project.

And I want that the zfcuser routes are child routes of my admin route

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I've tried overcoming recently, not using ZfcUser but whilst developing my own modules. There are a few solutions but the most suitable would depend on the type of application you're developing.

The easiest solution would be to override the `zfcuser` route path and prefixing it with `admin`.

```
return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'zfcuser' => [
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/admin/user',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

If you're like me and want all you `admin` routes contained under a single route then you're better off removing the `zfcuser` route completely and implementing your own which could utilize the ZfcUser controllers.

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent;
use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager;

class Module
{
    public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
    {
        $events = $moduleManager->getEventManager();
        $events->attach(ModuleEvent::EVENT_MERGE_CONFIG, array($this, 'onMergeConfig'));
    }

    public function onMergeConfig(ModuleEvent $event)
    {
        $configListener = $event->getConfigListener();
        $configuration = $configListener->getMergedConfig(false);

        if (isset($configuration['router']['routes']['zfcuser']))
        {
            unset($configuration['router']['routes']['zfcuser']);
        }

        $configListener->setMergedConfig($configuration);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the add.
I will try this tonight, or tomorrow. 

Feedback soon ;-)

Comment: No worries, depending on what method you go with, just remember to override anything that references the old routes E.g. `zfcuser/logout`.